# remove index.php in codeigniter. my project is in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove `index.php` in codeigniter.my codegiter project is inside `public_html/programemis/lasoona/`.I have my `.htacess` file with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lasoona/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but its not working .any one please help.

Comment: That looks okay to me, are you getting a 404? Do you have `base_url` defined? What about `$config['index_page']`, is it empty?

Comment: Good point @kisaragi .... Adding one more thing remove QSA

Comment: $config['index_page'] is empty but still not working

Comment: `index.php/$1` would produce `index.php/foo/bar`, which isn't going to be a valid url, unless you have path_info enabled. perhaps you want `index.php?$1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /programemis/lasoona/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /programemis/lasoona/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: dear @aeonsleo , try this one too but sill not working.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of solutions posted online for this. Here's from stackoverflow itself:

[Codeigniter remove index.php - htaccess localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192551/codeigniter-remove-index-php-htaccess-localhost)

If it won't work, here's another (this works for me) based from:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Just be mindful of the location of **.htaccess**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use it and working try it. If dont work remove programemis folder from RewriteBase. If you get same problem I recommented create a sub-domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /programemis/lasoona/
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```